# How to split string using split() using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to split the 1&90 into 1 and 90 and assign in different variable.

```
$(document).on("click", "a[name='delete_user_journal']", function (event, element) {

    var el = $(element);
    event.preventDefault();
    var j_id = $(this).attr("href");
    alert(j_id); // 1&90
}
```

Comment: @Tushar then output is 1,90. i want to assign 1 and 90 in different variables.is it possible to split by using "var arr = ju_id.split('&');
        var n = $(".delete_user_journal").html(arr[0]);"

Comment: Yes, `var arr = j_id.split('&'); var myFirstVar = arr[0];// 1 var mySecondVar = arr[1]; // 90`

Comment: @Tushar thanks man.. :)